# NSDictionary that doesn't change

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, static, nsdictionary

I want to make myself things easier so I'm creating a dictionary that is used by other function (to reach key by object or object by key) but that dictionary is always static. Is this fine way to do it or I need property or something else?

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithCategoriesAndStrings
{
    return @{
             kNewsCategoryAll       : @(NewsCategoryAll),
             kNewsCategoryRadio     : @(NewsCategoryRadio),
             kNewsCategoryEconomics : @(NewsCategoryEconomics),
             kNewsCategoryCulture   : @(NewsCategoryCulture),
             kNewsCategorySport     : @(NewsCategorySport),
             kNewsCategoryTravel    : @(NewsCategoryTravel),
             kNewsCategoryMusic     : @(NewsCategoryMusic),
             kNewsCategorySociety   : @(NewsCategorySociety),
             kNewsCategoryHealth    : @(NewsCategoryHealth)
             };
}
```

So now I always access this same dictionary through function [self dictionaryWithCategoriesAndString];

Note: Those are keys are static strings declared at top and objects are NSNumbers with integer.

Comment: For future reference, if you have working code and just want to know if there is a better way, post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than exposing the static to the entire class, you could create it within the method, and initialise it only once with gcd:

This *is* thread safe.

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithCategoriesAndStrings {
    static NSDictionary *dict;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dict = @{
                 kNewsCategoryAll       : @(NewsCategoryAll),
                 kNewsCategoryRadio     : @(NewsCategoryRadio),
                 kNewsCategoryEconomics : @(NewsCategoryEconomics),
                 kNewsCategoryCulture   : @(NewsCategoryCulture),
                 kNewsCategorySport     : @(NewsCategorySport),
                 kNewsCategoryTravel    : @(NewsCategoryTravel),
                 kNewsCategoryMusic     : @(NewsCategoryMusic),
                 kNewsCategorySociety   : @(NewsCategorySociety),
                 kNewsCategoryHealth    : @(NewsCategoryHealth)
                 };
    });

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: This.  The dispatch_once means that this only happens one time.  Making it static allows it to stick around.  This means that you have an item that you can access, that doesn't disappear after you've used it, and that only gets created once, so you're always accessing the same structure.  For the OP, you could also create a singleton if you really wanted to through an extension of this method.  Try googling on Matt Galloway singleton, or just go here: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Just one more question. If it wasn't class method but a normal one would @John answer be correct or yours again just with (-)? Thanks.

Comment: @ŽeljaHuber You could use this as an instance method in exactly the same way. i.e. with a `-` not a `+`. Static variables in methods are accessible to all instances, and using `dispatch_once()` means that it is still thread safe.

Comment: @AlexZavatone A Class (not an _instance_ of a class) is a singleton. There is only one, so technically, this is a singleton solution.

Comment: Thanks Abi.  I was just encouraging the OP to move into a class singleton as in Matt's link.  Don't know what is the best term to explain it though. Taking it that extra step has lead to much more predictable projects for me.

Comment: @AlexZavatone Not everyone is keen on singletons in Cocoa. They have their place, but for something as simple as this a class method is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You will be creating a new NSDictionary every time you call this method, so you won't really be accessing the same dictionary as it will just be a new identical one each time. You won't be able to make a property either if you're using it statically. Maybe something a little more like this just so you are accessing the same dictionary each time.

To access this in an instance method, you could use [[self class] dictionaryWithCategoriesAndStrings].

```
static NSDictionary* dict;


+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithCategoriesAndStrings
{
    if(dict == nil)
    {
        dict = @{
         kNewsCategoryAll       : @(NewsCategoryAll),
         kNewsCategoryRadio     : @(NewsCategoryRadio),
         kNewsCategoryEconomics : @(NewsCategoryEconomics),
         kNewsCategoryCulture   : @(NewsCategoryCulture),
         kNewsCategorySport     : @(NewsCategorySport),
         kNewsCategoryTravel    : @(NewsCategoryTravel),
         kNewsCategoryMusic     : @(NewsCategoryMusic),
         kNewsCategorySociety   : @(NewsCategorySociety),
         kNewsCategoryHealth    : @(NewsCategoryHealth)
         };
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Almost right.  Every time that selector is executed, a new NSDictionary is created.  That is bad.  It should only be created once, and it should only be created lazily.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *categoryDict;

- (NSDictionary *) categoryDict
{
    if( !_categoryDict)
    { 
       _categoryDict = @{  @"Key" :@"value" , ....};
    }
    return _categoryDict;
}
```

Now the dictionary is only created once. and you can get to the dictionary using dot notation.

Comment: It is a class method, returning a static NSDictionary will work just fine.

Comment: This requires an instance of the class, which is not necessarily what the OP wants.

Comment: @Abizern but the OP said "So now I always access this same dictionary through function [self dictionaryWithCategoriesAndString];" even though he wrote it as a class method.  But in the end, I like your answer better.

Comment: Through personal choice I would also make it a property, but without knowing how exactly the OP was using the Dictionary, I think the answer was best kept as a static method.